# How to build an adaptive layout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

So I am trying to Follow this documentation to achieve something similar to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive), this is where the CardTitle moves and image; but the `Title` and `Description` on this documentation do not seem to be available on Cards now? I can not access that when I try to create a Card. Biggest issue Card does not have Description anymore, maybe this needs to be updated or how can I achieve this. I am trying to something similar to the image shown.
[image]

Code from the Documentation.

```
   @Composable
    fun Card(
        imageUrl: String,
        title: String,
        description: String
    ) {
        var showMore by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
        BoxWithConstraints {
            if (maxWidth < 400.dp) {
                Column {
                    Image(imageUrl)
                    Title(title)
                }
            } else {
                Row {
                    Column {
                        Title(title)
                        Description(
                            description = description,
                            showMore = showMore,
                            onShowMoreToggled = { newValue ->
                                showMore = newValue
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    Image(imageUrl)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Biggest issue Card does not have Description anymore, maybe this needs
> to be updated or how can I achieve this. I am trying to something
> similar to the image shown.

This is not an issue because the sample above is for demonstrating flexible layout based on screen size using `BoxWithConstraints`. When you build your layouts you don't have follow this exact pattern.

You can do it in many ways including

```
Column {
   Image(imageUrl)
   Title(title)
   // You can add a description that is one line with ellipsis overflow for instance. Or it's font size can be smaller than title
}
```

In your example demonstrator preferred to not show when screen size is less than 400.dp.

`BoxWithConstraints` is suitable for building a selective layouts based on max or min width/height from its `Constraints`